# C : Array of strings - Can input only n-1 strings for an input size of n

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

I have to sort strings in a lexicographical order using the Bubble Sort technique without using any library functions. I have written the following code which is working fine in sorting the strings. 
But the problem is that if I give **n** as the input (say n = 4), I can enter only **n-1** strings (only 3 strings). 
The problem can be solved by running the for loops from 0 to n, but that isn't a logical solution.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
void swap(int indx[], int j)
{
    int temp;
    temp = indx[j];
    indx[j] = indx[j+1];
    indx[j+1] = temp;
}
void sort(char **str, int indx[], int n)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n-i-1; j++)
        {
            k = 0;
            while(str[j][k] != '\0')
            {
                if((str[indx[j]][k]) > (str[indx[j+1]][k]))
                {
                    swap(indx, j);
                    break;
                }
                else if((str[indx[j]][k]) < (str[indx[j+1]][k]))
                    break;
                else
                    k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
void display(char **str, int indx[], int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("Sorted strings : ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", str[indx[i]]);
}
int main(void)
{
    char **str;
    int n, i, j, *indx;
    printf("Enter no. of strings : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    str = (char **) malloc (n * (sizeof(char *)));
    indx = (int *) malloc (n * sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        str[i] = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter the strings : ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        gets(str[i]);
        indx[i] = i;
    }
    sort(str, indx, n);
    display(str, indx, n);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand... 1) why can you only enter n-1 strings? You don't say what the problem is. 2) why is it "not logical" to run the loops from 0 to n?

Comment: Note: the C Standard says the function `malloc()` is declared in `<stdlib.h>` (not `<malloc.h>`); also it doesn't talk about any header named `<malloc.h>` at all.

Comment: @KScottPiel To answer your first question, let's take this example that if I give 4 to the "Enter number of strings", then I can actually enter only 3 strings.
To answer your second question, if we start the array index from 0, we generally go upto n-1. So if we traverse the array from 0 to n, we are actually traversing one extra element, which is not logical as per my knowledge.

Comment: You don't traverse the array from 0 to n, you traverse that array from zero to one-less-than-n.

Comment: Ah, found the problem.

Comment: I still don't understand **why** you can only enter three strings? If `n == 4` then str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3] is four strings and you traverse from i = 0..3 `for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )`

Comment: @ElchononEdelson  that's exactly what I did. But if I traverse the array from zero to one-less-than-n, then I am having that problem. If I try to traverse it from zero to n, then I am getting the correct output. Now this is my question actually. What am I doing wrong? Btw, why can't I directly reply to your comments?

Comment: @KScottPiel even I can't understand why is that happening. That's why I'm asking if there's some other thing in the code that I need to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of `scanf()`. When you do `scanf("%d", &n)`, the `scanf()` function reads input until it finds an integer, and puts the value into `n`. However, when you entered that integer, you didn't just type '4', you typed '4' and pressed Enter. And the newline is still in the input buffer. The `gets()` function, on the other hand, reads input up to *and including* the first newline, and the newline character is discarded. So when you're reading the input strings, the gets call to `gets()` reads the newline, and returns immediately. And then, the first string that you enter is read by the second call to `gets()`...

Incidentally, The `gets()` function should never, ever, under any circumstances, *ever* be used for real programs, because it doesn't allow you to limit input. Better would be to use `fgets()`. `fgets(str[i], BUFFERSIZE-1, stdin)`.

Comment: I can't seem to find the reference at the moment, but my recollection is that C experts recommend not to use `scanf()`. The suggested alternative is to read a line of input using `fgets()` and then use `sscanf()` on that.

Comment: fgets() is taking all the newlines after each string entry, since I am pressing Enter after entering each string. To be true, I am not much familiar with the sscanf() syntax.

Comment: Yes, `fgets()` copies the newline, unlike `gets()` which discards it. It should be fairly simple to find the '\n' at the end of each string and write a 0 over it. (Other concerns: If the input line is too long, the buffer will not be null-terminated.)

Comment: Okay managed to solve the problem by consuming the newline from the `scanf()`, and then checking for newline in each of the `fgets()` entry and replacing the newline with null. This at least seems to be a better solution than traversing the array from 0 to n. Thanks a lot.   .

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)
{
char **str;
int n=4, i, j, *indx;
printf("Enter no. of strings : ");
//scanf("%d", &n);
str = (char **) malloc (n * (sizeof(char *)));
indx = (int *) malloc (n * sizeof(int));
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    str[i] = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
printf("Enter the strings : ");
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    gets(str[i]);
    indx[i] = i;
}
sort(str, indx, n);
display(str, indx, n);
}
```

//if i comment out scanf and give int the value it works fine //
              so the problem is use of fgets just after scanf as scanf leave a newline character in the buffer//               so consume it before using fgets

Comment: Yes, managed to get a solution by consuming the newline from the `scanf()` and then checking for newline in the `fgets()` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the line where you have to input the string. Instead of:

```
gets(str[i]);
```

type:

```
scanf("%s",str[i]);
```